# repeated substring pattern that is consistent throughout the entire given string -- python

Tags: python, substring, repeat

```
def repeated(s):
    repeatedStrs = []
    i = len(s)/2 #get middle index of s
    j = i = int(i)
    # as long as index doesn't become 0, i.e., we are not comparing 
    # two single letters(the first letter of s and the last letter of s)
    while i != 0: 
        #if the first i letters are equal to the last i letters
        if s[0:i] == s[-i:len(s)]: 
            # adding the repeated string (only repeated in beginning 
            # and end) to a list so we can later confirm that this repeated 
            # string repeats consecutively throught the entire string
            repeatedStrs.append(s[0:i]) 
        i -= 1
    count = 0
    for repeatedStr in repeatedStrs:
        lenOfRepStr = len(repeatedStr)
        #ensuring that the repeated string fits perfectly into the string
        if (lenOfRepStr > 0 and len(s) % lenOfRepStr == 0): 
            # len(s) - lenOfRepStr + 2 --> ensures that we don't go
            # past the highest index since we compare the next lenOfRepStr
            # indexes below; we move up by lenOfRepStr each pass

            for q in range(0, len(s) - lenOfRepStr + 2, lenOfRepStr):               
                # compares adjacent lenOfRepStr letters to see if it 
                # is not equal to our repeated substring 
                if repeatedStr != s[q : (q+lenOfRepStr)]: 
                    # breaks so we move onto the next choice of repeatedStr 
                    # that was in our array of repeatedStrs
                    break 
                #this is our counter so we can ensure that for every adjacent 
                # pairs of the repeatedStr, we go through the 
                # entire string 's' the exact same times
                count += 1 
                # seeing if we had the substring the exact same times that
                # it can fit in the string 's'
                if count == len(s)/lenOfRepStr: 
                    return True
    return False
```

This is the problem I am attempting: https://edabit.com/challenge/L2nw2N2YqZCboiaYM

I know that there are way quicker and simpler ways at solving this but I want to solve it this way since I already started

so here was the process of thinking I went through: I would check to see if there was any repeating substring that occurs at the start and the end of the string 's'. I would continue to find other options of substrings that occurred at the beginning and end. Then, once I built an array of these various options of repeating substrings that repeated at the beginning and the end of the words, then I started to check if these repeating substrings occurred consecutively throughout the entire string, if I found one like this I return True, otherwise, False.so I am trying to figure out why this is not working for extremely large strings.

THis is the string that isnt working (it should return false but it returns true:

fqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmtbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlh

and this is the substring it tells me I get:
fqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlh

apparently:
the substring found: fqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlh

doesn't equal

fqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmsbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlhfqmtbezecsinaikkjiehlkyqhmbytyvuyllxdlsggxqehktsyojzxnyhqvjepwzafzlsbufugkuabsnoypvlfuqeuxlh

Comment: Do you need to detect recurring substrings in the recurring substring? Image a pattern like `xxyyzzxxyyzz`. Local patterns would be `xx`, `yy` and `zz`. However, the global pattern would be `xxyyzz`.

Comment: No, the only correct repeating pattern in here would be xxyyzz. The repeating pattern has to occur through the entire string, i.e, it has to be consecutive

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
count = 0
for repeatedStr in repeatedStrs:
    lenOfRepStr = len(repeatedStr)
    ...
```

Should be

```
for repeatedStr in repeatedStrs:
    count = 0
    lenOfRepStr = len(repeatedStr)
    ...
```